# IAB helper is not set up. Can't perform operation(On Android 2.3.3)

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I implement `In-app Billing Version 3` in App. `InAppBilling` is working fine on `Android 2.3.5,4.0,4.1 and 4.2`, But every time when i test the app on `Android 2.3.3` the app is crash. All the classes of `InAppBilling` copied from my `SDK` (/extras/google/play_billing/).
I cleared the cache from Google Play Store App but nothing happened.

This is crash log

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: IAB helper is not set up. Can't perform operation: launchPurchaseFlow
at com.test.demo.inappbilling.util.IabHelper.checkSetupDone(IabHelper.java:782)
at com.test.demo.inappbilling.util.IabHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(IabHelper.java:372)
at com.test.demo.inappbilling.util.IabHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(IabHelper.java:338)
com.test.demo.AfterLoginScreen.onClick(AfterLoginScreen.java:215)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2532)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9277)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I guess on 2.3.3 IAB fails initialization. when you do "new IabHelper" then "mBillingHelper.startSetup(new SomeListener) ...".... What is the error that comes in OnIabSetupFinishedListener IabResult.getMessage() ?

Answer (score 2):

check google play service version,

```
 int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                        .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(mContext);

                // Showing status
                if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am quoting developer.android.com

> If your device is running Android 3.0, In-app Billing requires version 5.0.12 (or higher) of the MyApps application. If your device is running any other version of Android, In-app Billing requires version 2.3.4 (or higher) of the Google Play application.

Comment: but it working fine on Android 2.3.5, Only crashing on Android 2.3.3

Comment: Maybe it's a google play issue. And it should be higher than 2.3.4 so the 2.3.3 will crash